# Difference between this.get('model') and modelFor

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am quite new to ember and don't really get the difference between two types of syntax. Where and in which situations should i use one or another. I.e. Which one is more suitable for usage in Routes and which one for Controllers.

```
this.get('model')
```

As opposed to

```
this.modelFor('artists/show')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
this.get('model') //controller call
this.modelFor('someRoute') //route call
```

In Ember, a routes `setupController` hook by default performs this one line of code:

```
setupController: function(controller, model){
   controller.set('model', model);
}
```

This takes whatever is returned from the `model` hook and sets the controller's `model` property with this value. From within the controller, `this.get('model')` is the proper way to access this model. Also, a developer can override this hook and do something different, like set `model` equal to some child property of what is returned from the `model` hook (`controller.set('model', model.prop)`. This is worth noting, because when you call `this.modelFor` from another route, you DO NOT get the route's associated controller's model that is set by `setupController`. You get whatever is returned from the `model` hook, which under the covers is the route's `currentModel` property if I remember correctly.

Comment: To be precise "it takes whatever is returned from the `model` hook and sets the controller's `model` property with the result of resolving that promise".

Comment: indeed I should have noted that subtlety.

Answer (score 6):

this.get('model') fetches the model from the current controller scope.

this.modelFor('artists/show') fetches the model that would be in scope at the specified route.

Answer (score 4):

this.get('model') would be used in the controller in a computed property, say.

this.modelFor is for a route to access the model of a parent route say to reuse or resolve to it.

Comment: You say "or resolve it", but by this point, the parent route model is already resolved.

Comment: Yes but the child route can resolve to it as well. I've edited and put in the word "to"

Answer (score 3):

This two are defined on different ember objects - `model` property on controller and `modelFor` **method** on route.

First of all, the `model` property, and executing it as `this.get('model')` only gets the object that is already set on the `model` property in controller. It means, that it gets anything that was set up during the `setupController` hook in route. You cannot fetch any data from API using this statement. Moreover, it allows you only to get the object that was set on current controller (`this` scope).

#### When is it set up?

In `setupController` hook. The life-cycle of route first resolves all model-related callbacks (`beforeModel`, `model` and `afterModel`). After that, it executes `setupController` with these arguments: `(controller, model)`. It means that it has access to all that resolved from `model` hook and the current `controller` instance. By default, the `setupController` sets the `model` on `controller.model` property:

```
controller.set('model', model);
```

You can override that with your custom code and e.g. set your model on `myModel` property - it depends on you. But if you want to get your model in your controller code, you have to always query the property you set your model on.

#### How #modelFor works?

`modelFor` is defined on routes instances and allows you to get the `model` hook result from any route in your application. You can use it in your `setupController` hook as follows:

```
controller.set('model', this.modelFor('myOtherRoute'));
```

This behaviour can be considered as improving consistency across the app - it explicitly says that in current route and controller you use the same data as in `myOtherRoute`.

How does it work? It queries `myOtherRoute.model` property, that stores the `model` resolved data of that route. The implementation is fairly simple - it looks up your `container` (global object that stores your routes, controllers, components, etc.) for the route named `myOtherRoute` and gets it `model` property.