# How to pass Array Of Objects from One route to Another Route in EmberJS (Without using query params)

Tags: ember.js, routes, query-string, session-storage

As I am new to ember i don't know how to pass an Array of Objects from one route to another route in ember? (without using query params).Do i need a SessionStorage?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through [How do I ask a good question?])(https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with sub / nested routes with `modelFor`

see: [Difference between this.get('model') and modelFor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30402235/difference-between-this-getmodel-and-modelfor)

and: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/passing-models-to-controller-via-modelfor-and-setupcontroller-or-inject/8726

docs: https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.3/classes/Route/methods/modelFor?anchor=modelFor

is this what you mean?

Comment: Oh..Thank You! But what if, i want to pass an Object from one controller to another controller...(I am not assigning my object to model here!)

Comment: why do you want to pass objects around in controllers? (also, why not use the model hook?)

Comment: there is controllerFor: https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.3/classes/Route/methods/controllerFor?anchor=controllerFor

Answer (score 2):

Often when data needs to be shared between routes, it should either be saved in the local data store using Ember Data, or you can use a Service. Be careful not to create too many services holding data or you can end up with a mess.

For example, say you create a service called formOptions. You can inject the service in your routes and get the data like `formOptions.myData`.

More on services: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/services/